# Discord.py Remind Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have the bot where it can respond to messages sent like "good morning" "hello" etc. I want to implement an event where a user can set a reminder, so the bot can ping them. Ive looked at so many other examples and have been messing with it for weeks.

heres my code:

```
import asyncio


class RemindCommand(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def remind(self, ctx, time, *, task):

    def convert(time):
      pos = ['s', 'm', 'h', 'd']

      time_dict = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 3600 * 24}

      unit = time[-1]

      if unit not in pos:
        #        print("Failed Unit!")
        return -1
      try:
        val = int(time[:-1])

  #     print("Pass Unit!")
      except:
        return -2

        return val * time_dict[unit]

    converted_time = convert(time)

    if converted_time == -1:
      await ctx.send("you didnt imput the time correctly.")
      return

    if converted_time == -2:
      await ctx.send("The number must be an integer")
      return

    await ctx.send(f"Okay, i will remind you to **{task}** at **{time}**.")

    await asyncio.sleep(converted_time)
    await ctx.send(
      f"{ctx.author.mention} your reminder for **{task}** has finished!")


def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(RemindCommand(client))


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: So what is the problem you have?

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot t add this, so the message will respond to the "good morning" etc. but will not respond when i try .remind 5s hello or anything of the sort.